# How to build a proper bar plot and facet grid in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to create a plot just like this one:

https://www.statista.com/statistics/1109004/coronavirus-covid19-cases-rate-us-americans-by-state/

but also distinguish between democratic and republican states.

I also tried a geom_line plot but I can't figure out how to make the Democrats graph blue and the republican one red.
I have to admit that I copied a lot from the ggplot attempts from other stackoverflow posts and really don't understand how to transfer it to my dataset.
This is my code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(htmltab)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)
library(wesanderson)
library(usmap)

corona_usa_simple <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/us_simplified.csv")
corona_us_states <- corona_usa_simple %>% 
select(- FIPS, -`Country/Region`) %>%  rename(State=`Province/State`)

us_states_population <- corona_us_states %>%
    group_by(State, Date) %>% 
    summarise(totalPopulation = sum(Population),
              totalConfirmed = sum(Confirmed),
              totalDeaths = sum(Deaths))
wiki_governors <- htmltab("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_governors",
 header = 2) %>% slice(-1)

wiki_governors[23,3] <- "Democratic" #Democratic-Farmer-Labor to Democratic

corona_party_states <- left_join(wiki_governors, us_states_population, by= "State") %>%
select(- Governor, - Born, - `Prior public experience`, - Inauguration, - `End of term`, - `Past governors`)

corona_party_states <-transform(corona_party_states, percentage = totalConfirmed/totalPopulation)
options(scipen = 999)

corona_party_states <- transform(corona_party_states, CasesPop = totalConfirmed*100000/totalPopulation) %>%
  rename(state = State) 

# plot facet grid
xmin <- as.Date("2020-01-30")
xmax <- as.Date("2020-08-30")

ggplot(corona_party_states, aes(Date, CasesPop)) + 
  geom_line(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
    alpha = I(.1)))+
  theme(legend.position = "left", 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 6), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.3)),
         fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))+
  scale_x_date() +
 labs(title = "Corona Party",
       y = "Cases/100K Pop", x = "Date") + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Party))

#bar plot
options(scipen = 999)
ggplot(data = corona_party_states) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = totalConfirmed, color = state))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
  theme(legend.position = "left", 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 3), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 3),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.5)),
         fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))+
  ggtitle("Corona Cases by party")+
  ylab("Confirmed Cases")+
  xlab("Timeline")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the web page you shared you want a bar plot with colors according to party. After checking your code you had issues with the variables for grouping. Also the data you get from party had two class of Democrats. So, I have modified your code slightly and following the web page I have sketched the code for a plot (I have used the data of all confirmed cases):

Initially all the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(htmltab)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)
library(wesanderson)
library(usmap)

corona_usa_simple <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/us_simplified.csv")
corona_us_states <- corona_usa_simple %>% 
  select(- FIPS, -`Country/Region`) %>%  rename(State=`Province/State`)

us_states_population <- corona_us_states %>%
  group_by(State, Date) %>% 
  summarise(totalPopulation = sum(Population),
            totalConfirmed = sum(Confirmed),
            totalDeaths = sum(Deaths))
wiki_governors <- htmltab("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_governors",
                          header = 2) %>% slice(-1)

wiki_governors[23,3] <- "Democratic" #Democratic-Farmer-Labor to Democratic

corona_party_states <- left_join(wiki_governors, us_states_population, by= "State") %>%
  select(- Governor, - Born, - `Prior public experience`, - Inauguration, - `End of term`, - `Past governors`)

corona_party_states <-transform(corona_party_states, percentage = totalConfirmed/totalPopulation)

corona_party_states <- transform(corona_party_states, CasesPop = totalConfirmed*100000/totalPopulation) %>%
  rename(state = State)
```

Now the code for plot, I made a new variable for party in order to only have two groups:

```
#Do some replacements for cleaning
corona_party_states$PartyC <- ifelse(grepl('Democrat',corona_party_states$Party.1),
                                     'Democratic','Republican')
#bar plot
ggplot(data = corona_party_states,
       aes(x=reorder(state,totalConfirmed),
           y=totalConfirmed,fill=PartyC)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  coord_flip()+
  ggtitle("Corona Cases by party")+
  ylab("Confirmed Cases")+
  xlab("State")+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm having a hard time learning all the features of ggplot but this is exactly what I wanted!